# keyboard events not working with MAC touch bar in React Js after first submit (on textarea form)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, textarea

I have a weird issue where MAC touch bar (key input) events (word suggestions) are not working when after I submit the textarea input....The textarea inputs are unable to trigger any keyevents in React (not sure about other frameworks)

Scenario:

**Step 1 :** Type something in textarea and press Enter.

**Step 2 :** Try now to enter something via Mac touch bar (there are word suggestions on touch bar that appear) try touching them... no keyboard event  is triggering...

Now if we try to type something from the physical keyboard and then use the Touch bar suggestions and we can see that it starts working again....

This issue happens only after clearing or resetting the textarea element...

I need this to work with Mac touch bar just like regular input event....

Created an example in stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-er5v6c?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: this is really weird. I assume something wrong with mac touchbar, async call and useState. I'd recommend try to use react context to change the input, instead of a hook, and see how it goes

Comment: nope... tried that as well... I also used redux to trigger the same functionality...
I defer it has something to do with async call... shouldnt make any difference in that case...
Looking for a more elaborate solution in this part... This is a simplest usage I can  put together without usage of any external lib (redux) also without any needed context... @Georgy